# Change float for last ul item

Tags: html, css

i have problem with floating. I am doing navigation bar. It should be inline with left floating and last item have to be on end of line (right float).

I tried margin-left but it is not good...

```
ul {
 position: static;
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left:150px;
 margin-top: 11px;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}

ul  li{
 float: left;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

ul li a{
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 72px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 19px;
 }

 ul li:last-child a{
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0%;
 }
```

Comment: Make a sample on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You don't need `position: static;`

Comment: use float:right for li:last-child

Comment: Personally, i find floating the last-item right strange, why not float them all left, with margin-right and just remove the margin-right on the last child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should float this last item, as simple as:

```
ul li:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/eLLa4/ (with removal of all extra declarations when I didn't see how they'd be useful in this fiddle, like relative positioning of a children not moving top, right, bottom or left...)

Complete CSS:

```
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: 150px;
 margin-top: 11px;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
 ul li:last-child {
  float: right;
}

ul li a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 72px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 19px;
}
```

Comment: I thought he just needed the last item to be last in line.. Didn't fully understand his question

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ul li:last-child{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jc84t/)

Answer (score 0):

Make the last `<li>` `float: right` then:

http://jsfiddle.net/YDAkV/

```
ul li:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I see my problem was: ul li:last-child a {}

have a nice day ;)

Comment: You might want to accept an answer below as someone pointed that out and led you to that discovery